# Safari browser will not load a ".php" page

Tags: php

I am working on a Mac and my website is on a dedicated server - when I try to load a ".php" page, the browser thinks it should download it instead  of display it - why is this happening?

Comment: Is your server configured to parse php files and execute php code in them? It may not know what to do with it and just be serving the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure php is running on your server.

And also make sure IIS or Apache (or whatever your webserver is) is running as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver probably doesn't send the [corect MIME-type](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-mimetype.htm) with PHP-files. Different browsers might handle it differently. If you are sure that the server send the correct headers, check your safari options.